# Can't compile Android project with gradle after adding a library

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Before adding a library to my Android project the layout was like this:

- MyappProject

  - Myapp

    - build.gradle
- settings.gradle
- build.gradle

The top level build.gradle has always been empty, with the settings.gradle file containing only:

```
include ':Myapp'
```

I obtained a library project which I was able to import successfully into Android Studio, so I presume that the gradle files within it were fine. I now have the following structure:

- MyappProject

  - Myapp

    - build.gradle
  - libraries

    - Library

      - LibrarySubProject1

        - build.gradle
      - ....
      - build.gradle
- settings.gradle
- build.gradle

...and the top level settings gradle now looks like:

```
include ':Myapp'
include ':libraries:Library'
```

I've also updated Myapp's build.gradle so it includes the extra last line in dependencies here:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile files('libs/commons-lang3-3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsoup-1.7.3.jar')
    compile project(':libraries:Library')
}
```

Unfortunately, any attempt to do anything with gradle (sync files, build etc.) now gets me the following:

```
Gradle 'MyappProject' project refresh failed:
     Configuration with name 'default' not found.
     Gradle settings
```

Any changes to the settings appear to have no effect, and Android Studio keeps the settings set to "use default gradle wrapper". 
From what I understand, that means that there is a problem with the top level build.gradle along the lines of this file not containing sufficient information to build the sub projects. But, perhaps I have misunderstood, as Myapp used to build and Library also seems fine. Removing the compile project(':libraries:Library') allows gradle file syncing again, but I would like to use that library...

Any suggestions as to how to fix this would be welcome.

Edited to add build.gradle from Library. Top level:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    version = VERSION_NAME
    group = GROUP

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

From the next level:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}

apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push/master/gradle-mvn-push.gradle'
```

Comment: Sounds like `:libraries:Library` doesn't (implicitly or explicitly) declare a `default` configuration, in which case it isn't possible to refer to it using a project dependency.

Comment: Thanks. I've been looking through gradle documentation, but it is not clear to me how one might declare a configuration. Would you mind pointing me at what I should be reading, please?

Comment: Could you show your build.gradle from Library project?

Comment: I've added some build.gradle files as requested.

Comment: You shouldn't have to manually declare a `default` configuration; the `android-library` plugin should probably take care of that. I don't know the details of how this plugin works, but you should be able to find a solution after studying the official Gradle Android plugin docs, which contain a lot of information on project dependencies and such.

Comment: OK, I'll keep on searching through the docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot have project inside a project in Android Studio. You can only have modules so change your project structure as shown below so that it will be compliant for the allowed project - module level structure.

```
MyappProject
   Myapp
    build.gradle
   libraries
    LibrarySubProject1
     build.gradle
     ....
settings.gradle
build.gradle(Root only one)
```

Now do the following with your build.gradle files

**1. Root level `build.gradle` file**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

If you have something in your library project's root level build.gradle file include that also in this root level build.gradle file because only root is allowed to have which will automatically be included in each of the sub level's build.gradle files while compilation .

**2. LibraryProject's `build.gradle` file**

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 19
        }

        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }

            instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

            debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
            release.setRoot('build-types/release')
        }
    }

    apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push/master/gradle-mvn-push.gradle'
```

**3. Your main module's `build.gradle` file should look like**

```
apply plugin: 'android'

        android {
            compileSdkVersion 19
            buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

            defaultConfig {
                minSdkVersion 14
                targetSdkVersion 19
            }
       }

       dependencies {
           //YOUR MODULE DEPENDENCIES
           compile project(':libraries:LibrarySubProject1')
       }
```

**your `settings.gradle` file will be like**

```
  include ':Myapp'
  include ':libraries:LibrarySubProject1'
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem was solved simply by deleting the line containing

```
maven_push.gradle
```

this line was trying to upload the project to maven while I didn't need to.

Answer (score 2):

Your library has a multimodule build file structure:

```
Library
    LibrarySubProject1
        build.gradle
    ....
    build.gradle
```

with the two-level build.gradle file structure like Android Studio-made projects have, but that doesn't work for libraries. **MyApp** is pulling in the dependency for **:libraries:Library** but only sees that top-level build file with the `buildscript` and `allprojects` tags, and it can't find a default configuration in there to depend on.

Your library can't have a **settings.gradle** file to lead the way to **LibrarySubProject1/build.gradle**. What you'll need to move the library one directory level up to **Library**, and collapse the two **build.gradle** files down to one:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}

apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push/master/gradle-mvn-push.gradle'
```

I'm not sure what to do about the `VERSION` and `GROUP` stuff you're doing in the top-level **build.gradle**; you'll have to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

I just commented out line:
apply from: rootProject.file('gradle/maven-push.gradle') in
build.gradle(:library) since I don't want to publish this project at all, but I need it just as a library.

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.